# Windows Forms keeps being checkout in Visual Studio and Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, azure-devops, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Form project and I migrated it to Azure DevOps (TFVC - Team Foundation Version Control). I'm also using Visual Studio to develop it. The problem is that whenever I open a form by double clicking, all of its files (`.cs`, `.Desginer.cs`, and `.resx`) are checked out automatically. However, when I compare them with the latest version from the server, I see that no change has been made to them. This does not happen to other projects I have, which are mainly ASP.NET Core projects.

If I manually edit a file and undo my editions, Visual Studio knows that they are not changed and remove them from the list of pending changes. But here, without any changes, Visual Studio always lists them in the Pending Changes list. The problem is that each empty check-in litters the history. When we want to trace a change we see a lot of check-ins that have no change in them.

Why this happens and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing you can do except stop using the ancient, broken piece of garbage that is Team Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Forms keeps being checkout in Visual Studio and Azure DevOps

It seems a known issue about the Visual Studio:

[Opening a Windows Form in the designer checks out the file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/opening-a-windows-form-in-the-designer-checks-out/33543)

And this issue should be fixed in the Visual Studio 2017 version is 15.1 (26403.0).

Please try to update your Visual Studio version and re-check it.

Comment: My VS version is 2019 => `16.10.1`. So that can't be.